# Is it bad practice to allow specifying parameters in URL for POST

Tags: rest, url, post

Should parameters for POST requests (elements of the resource being created) be allowed to be added to the URL as well as in the body?

For example, let say I have a POST to create a new user at

```
/user
```

With the full set of parameters `name`, `email`, etc... in the body of the request.

However, I've seen many API's would accept the values in either the body or URL parameters like this:

```
/user?name=foo&email=foo@bar.com
```

Is there any reason this second option, allowing the parameters in the URL is bad practice?  Does it violate any component of REST?

Comment: It depends on how are you consuming those parameters. No fix rule for such things.

Comment: I think that URL parameters are fine but are unsuitable for sensitive information as they are stored in the users browser history. Also there is a limitation on how long the string can be

Comment: @ApulGupta  could you post an answer that shows different ways consuming would influence which place was more appropriate?

Comment: @Austin This is for a server-side API, only accessible via SSL.  This should not be implemented in the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intent of a query parameter is to help identify the target resource for a request. The body of a POST should be used to specify instructions to the server.

> The query component contains non-hierarchical data that, along with
> data in the path component (Section 3.3), serves to identify a
> resource within the scope of the URI's scheme and naming authority
> (if any).
>     -- [RFC 3986 Section 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4)
>
> The hierarchical path component and    optional query component serve
> as an identifier for a potential    target resource within that origin
> server's name space.
>     -- [RFC 7230 Section 2.7.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-2.7.1)

Comment: I see, so you might put a client API key in the URL as it identifies the 'specific target of the request', but should not put any elements of what is to be created in the URL like the new user name.

Comment: @Ray Correct. I would advise against the API key in particular, though, because it makes URL sharing impossible. Typically query parameters are used to do things like narrow down the responses in a collection query, such as `GET /users?country=US`

Comment: Thanks. Can you expand on what you mean by URL sharing?  The current API is SSL only, only authorized clients with dedicated client_id's and client_secret's (we adhere to oauth2).

Comment: @Ray Even so, any intermediate servers - caches, proxies, etc will still see the key. Anything that logs a URL will include the key. And if each end user has their own API key, if Bob sends Ted an email with a URL then Ted has Bob's credential.

Comment: It's via SSL only, so intermediate caches and proxies wouldn't see the query parameters in plain text.  It does get logged in our access logs, but they are as secure/insecure as our DB with the credentials. Our users should not be sharing URLs as they're partner specific, but in theory, 2 developers with the same partner could carelessly email each other a url if they work working on implementing.  However, they could also email the credentials between each other whether they were stored in the body or headers.  Is your recommendation just to avoid careless exposure?

Comment: I see.  While I'd like to use auth headers as the proper place to put them, it makes it more difficult for developers to consume the api (yes, I know...)  So it's a trade off of ease of use vs. security.

Comment: When we get around to building some SDK around the API, I'll probably revisit moving credentials from URL params.

Answer (score 0):

The Udacity Web Development course, be Steve Huffman (the man behind Reddit), recommends only using POST requests to update server side data. Steve highlights why using GET parameters to do so can be problematic.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'm not using GET, just POST.  The question is about specifying URL parameters during a POST request.